# Django, Empty module name when adding urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, router, django-urls

I have a Django rest framework API.

When registering the following router and adding the URL patterns the following error rises:

```py
...
File "/home/yovel/PycharmProjects/scr/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1011, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _sanity_check
ValueError: Empty module name
```

URLs file:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api', include('farm_api.urls'))
]
```

App's URLs file:

```py
from django.urls import include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from .views.group_view import GroupView

group_router = DefaultRouter()
group_router.register(prefix=r'groups', viewset=GroupView, basename='groups')
urlpatterns = [
    include('', group_router.urls)
]
```

Comment: I think that in: include('', group_router.urls) . The first parameter can't be empty. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urls/#include

Comment: You probably need to do urlpatterns = group_router.urls

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. In my problem, I had ' '(empty app) in INSTALLED_APPS. Got the error by removing '' from INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

settings.py Before:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    '',
]
```

settings.py After:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',        
    ]
```